# Mutithreading and anonymous classes and objects

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        }
        public synchronized void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}




/*

new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
            }).start();

*/
```

in the above code , we are creating a `new Thread` by creating an anonymous object of an anonymous class ( a subclass of the Runnable interface? )

but what when we pass this new `Runnable` object, it has **ITS OWN run()** method overloaded.so the *new Thread object still does not have its run() method overloaded.*the call by **new Thread(....).start** is to the run () of the thread which is still not overridden!!
am i getting it wrong , cause this code works

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Your threads are too fast to deadlock. Put a long sleep into the synchronized methods to force a deadlock.

Comment: i dint think you got me mate.this code IS working,,all i want to ask is how is it working !

Comment: we have never defined the run() method for the Thread object , yet it works..

Comment: Where is your problem? You define the run method with the Runnable Object you pass to the Thread constructors.

Comment: i am not worried about the deadlock..all i am interested in is how the call to   **new Thread( new Runnable...).start()** is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

```
public Thread(Runnable target)

Parameters:
target - the object whose run method is invoked when this thread is started. If null, this classes run method does nothing.
```

The `run()` method invoked on `start()` of the `Thread` object is the `run()` of the `Runnable`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have it wrong. First of all, you're confusing [overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) with [overriding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).

And second, [the javadoc of Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) explains how to create threads:

> There are two ways to create a new thread of execution. One is to declare a class to be a subclass of Thread. This subclass should override the run method of class Thread.[...]
>
> The other way to create a thread is to declare a class that implements the Runnable interface. That class then implements the run method. An instance of the class can then be allocated, passed as an argument when creating Thread, and started.

Comment: i wasn't confused between overloading or overriding or even deadlock for that matter.but anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: @user2837260 You used "oveloaded" where you meant "overridden" (twice). That's what JB is referring to.

Comment: oh yeah..just noticed..my bad

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you wonder about how something works in the JDK, [just have a look](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29). In this particular case, this would be what you would have found in the [Thread](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Thread.java#Thread.run%28%29) class:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Clearly, the method is defined and implemented, and the implementation says "call the passed-in Runnable's `run` method".